# Can RStudio ctrl-f search for newline or line feed or carriage return characters? e.g., find pairs of blank lines by searching for \n\n\n

Tags: r, regex, rstudio, newline, special-characters

You can use RStudio's ctrl-f search boxes (and using the Regex checkbox) to search for text and replace it with a new line by typing \n in the replace box, but you cannot type \n in the search box to find newlines. For example, if I want to find every place where my code has two blank lines in a row, and replace that pair of lines with just one blank line, what do I type in the search box?

If I am editing a .R file that has text like the example below, and I type ctrl-f, put a check in the Regex box, and type

\n\n\n

in the find box and type

\n\n

in the replace box,
it should be able to turn any two adjacent blank lines into just one.

If in the console I try something similar, it does work there, unlike trying to use ctrl-f:

```
before <- 
"line1 of text before just a single blank line

text line that initially was right before the two blank lines


text line that initially was after the two blank lines
last line of text."

after_desired <- 
"line1 of text before just a single blank line

text line that initially was right before the two blank lines

text line that initially was after the two blank lines
last line of text."

after_via_gsub <- gsub("\n\n\n", "\n\n", before)

# see that it worked
cat("BEFORE:\n", before, "\n\n") 
cat("AFTER: \n", after_via_gsub, "\n\n")
after_desired == after_via_gsub
```

Comment: Not awesome (and I don't know the RStudio IDE enough to opine much more on it), but you could do something like `clipr::write_clip(gsub("\n\n\n", "\n\n", paste(clipr::read_clip(), collapse = "\n")))`

Comment: Maybe try copying/pasting newlines into the search box? If that doesn't work it's probably just a limitation of the program.

Comment: I think it must be a limitation of Rstudio, but it would be nice to see their documentation acknowledge it.

Comment: Maybe someone can write an add-in that adds this functionality to Rstudio - Seems like the rstudioapi package could make such an add-in feasible.